# Converting my code to new Swift (2.2), dictionary doesn't have array function?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to convert my code to Swift 2.2 (I haven't opened this code since before Swift 2.0 was released). One of the things I've done a lot of is converting dictionarys to arrays using the .array function of dictionary items. This is apparently not a function anymore. What am I supposed to do? I thought the .elements function would work but I can't pull using an array [index] command.

Thanks!

Comment: And what do you want to do with this array? For example, if you simply want to iterate through your dictionary, you might do `for (key, value) in dictionary { ... }` where you can now reference the `key` and `value` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @Rob Well, first would be to organize by name (for a UI list), and second would be to get the name of the selected UI item in that list (so I need to pull from the index of the sorted array version of the dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish something like this. The easiest way is to change your model to be an array of dictionaries (or of custom objects):

```
var people = [
    ["name": "Rob", "city": "New York", "state": "NY", "street": "11 Wall Street"],
    ["name": "Jim", "city": "Washington", "state": "DC", "street": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue"],
    ["name": "Sue", "city": "Los Angeles", "state": "CA", "street": "4059 Mt Lee Dr."]
]
```

And, if you want to sort that by `name`:

```
people.sortInPlace { return $0["name"] < $1["name"] }
```

Or, let's imagine that you really have a dictionary where a unique identifier is the key:

```
var people = [
    34: ["name": "Rob", "city": "New York", "state": "NY", "street": "11 Wall Street"],
    42: ["name": "Jim", "city": "Washington", "state": "DC", "street": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue"],
    65: ["name": "Sue", "city": "Los Angeles", "state": "CA", "street": "4059 Mt Lee Dr."]
]
```

You can then build an array of identifiers sorted by name:

```
let sortedIdentifiers = people.map { return ($0, $1["name"]) }  // this builds array of items like `(34, "Rob")`
    .sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }                                       // this sorts that array by the second item (e.g. the name)
    .map { $0.0 }                                               // just return the identifiers sorted by name
```

You can now subscript the `sortedIdentifiers`, e.g.:

```
print(people[sortedIdentifiers[0]])
print(people[sortedIdentifiers[1]])
print(people[sortedIdentifiers[2]])
```

There are lots of ways to tackle this. If you edit your question to show us what your model looks like, we might be able to offer more specific solutions.